# Unable to get property 'get current' of undefined or null reference

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model

```
function listAllCategories() {
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostWebUrl);

var web = appCtxSite.get_web(); //Get the Web 

var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("NewsList"); //Get the List

var query = new SP.CamlQuery(); //The Query object. This is used to query for data in the List

query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Article Date\' Ascending=\'False\'/></OrderBy></Query>' + '<RowLimit>2</RowLimit></View>');


var items = list.getItems(query);

ctx.load(list); //Retrieves the properties of a client object from the server.
ctx.load(items);

var table = $("#tblcategories");
var innerHtml = "<table><p><h3></h3></p><tr><td></td><td><p></p><p></p></td></tr></table>";

//Execute the Query Asynchronously
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
        var itemInfo = '';
        var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var currentListItem = enumerator.get_current();
            innerHtml += "<table><p><h3>" + currentListItem.get_item('Article Title') + "</h3></p><tr><td><img src='" + currentListItem.get_item('Article Thumbnail').$2_1 + "'/></td><td><p> " + currentListItem.get_item('Article Body') + "</p><p> Posted In: <a href = '" + currentListItem.get_item('Article Categories').$2_1 + "'>" + currentListItem.get_item('Article Categories').$3_1 + "</a></p></td></tr></table>";
        }
        table.html(innerHtml);
    }),
    Function.createDelegate(this, fail)
    );
}
```

Comment: There is no explanation for the issue, just some code pasted in it.

Comment: By using above i got below error 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: I tried by adding internal field name but i am not getting item from list. still having issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for field initialization error is that in the view you are specifying `Article Date` field whereas in the success method you are trying to retrieve `Article Title` which obviously hasn't been requested at the time of query formation. It also looks like you are using `Display names` of the fields rather than `Internal names`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
var items;
function listAllCategories() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
    var appCtxSite = new SP.AppContextSite(ctx, hostWebUrl);
    var web = appCtxSite.get_web(); //Get the Web 
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("NewsList"); //Get the List
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery(); //The Query object. This is used to query for data in the List
    query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Article Date\' Ascending=\'False\'/></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>2</RowLimit></View>');
    items = list.getItems(query);   
    ctx.load(items);
    //Execute the Query Asynchronously
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var table = $("#tblcategories");
    var innerHtml = "<table><p><h3></h3></p><tr><td></td><td><p></p><p></p></td></tr></table>";     
    var listItemEnumerator = items.getEnumerator();         
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        innerHtml += "<table><p><h3>" + currentListItem.get_item('Article Title') + "</h3></p><tr><td><img src='" + currentListItem.get_item('Article Thumbnail').$2_1 + "'/></td><td><p> " + currentListItem.get_item('Article Body') + "</p><p> Posted In: <a href = '" + currentListItem.get_item('Article Categories').$2_1 + "'>" + currentListItem.get_item('Article Categories').$3_1 + "</a></p></td></tr></table>";
    }
    table.html(innerHtml);
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the internal name of any field. Sometimes this issue caused due to internal name miss match. You can follow this url http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/the-property-or-field-has-not-been-initialized-error-in-20910.aspx